# Prior that incentives dissimilarity of 2 parameters

Tags: statistics, bayesian

I have some binary data. I have a proposed partition of this data into partitions 1 and 2.

I want to test whether the data in models 1 and 2 were generated by two Bernoullis such that their parameters p1 and p2 differ by at least some threshold T, or both were generated by the same Bernoulli.

I am looking for a prior that would approximate this hard threshold but still be easy to work with computationally

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Choosing priors can be subjective when you don't know all the details of the problem, but this is what I would do:

Normally ignorance priors for Bernoulli parameters are chosen to be Beta distributions, with common choices being $\mathrm{Beta}(0,0)$,  $\mathrm{Beta}(1/2,1/2)$, and $\mathrm{Beta}(1,1)$ (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Bayesian_inference)). Here you are going to have to condition on your knowledge that $\left|p_1-p_2\right|>T$. So I would let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be independent $\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,\alpha)$ variables and then set the probability of the region where they are too close together equal to $0$, renormalizing elsewhere. Unless I had a complelling reason to do otherwise I'd pick $\alpha=1$ because otherwise this "cutoff" is going to lead to nasty integrals.

Then in the case where they have the same distribution I'd let the parameter $p$ have a $\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,\alpha)$ with the same $\alpha$ that I'd chosen before.